# How can I delete this blue vertical line in overleaf?

Tags: overleaf

It baffles me so much. I don't even know what it is.

[image]

In line 290. It cannot be deleted. And it seems not to be a comment. When I clicked the review tab in overleaf it shows nothing.

Comment: Are you collaborating with other users on that document? I'm guessing it's the cursor of another user.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thank you, I didn't collaborate with other users. I found that it is because I opened two tabs so overleaf would show that. Never realized this.

Comment: Ah, so your own cursor :) Feel free to write a "proper" answer-post as well, describing what it is, for any other people seeing this.

Comment: urelated but use `\centering`  not `\begin{center}..\end{center}` in figures (as floats already get vertical space)

Answer (score 2):

Well it is my cursor. If you open two tabs of the same file you will see it. Thanks to Torbjørn T. for the information.